# How hot is a primordial black hole and does it has angular momentum?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, angular-momentum, temperature, universe

I am fascinated by these elusive phenomenon, they are formed in the early stage of the universe where it is not homogeneous and some regions are very dense enough to undergoes gravitational collapse. I like to know how hot [primordial black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_black_hole) are if they are found today relative to the CMBR? Also since they are not formed from the dying star do they have angular momentum?

Answer (score 0):

Black holes have a temperature, given by:

$T = \frac{\hbar c^3}{8 \pi k G M}$

In other words, the temperature of the black hole depends only on its mass. So the temperature of the primordial black hole also depends only on its mass. We don't know with certainty what the mass of primordial black holes are, if they exist; furthermore if primordial black holes exist then they will almost surely have some mass range. So we do not know the answer to your question, although the moment one primordial black hole is identified and its mass measured, it's a trivial matter to calculate its temperature.

As for whether they have angular momentum, since we don't know what the initial conditions are in which primordial black holes form in, we also don't know what their initial angular momentums are - although it's hard to imagine that they would not have picked up some angular momentum over the 13+ billion years of the universe's evolution.

Comment: Who is this "we" you are talking about?